# Apache Cordova 5.4.0 gitignore

Tags: cordova

Was doing some google search and trying to find exactly what project specific folders/files should be in my gitignore file. Below is what I been thinking it should be, but not sure. Any recommendations?

```
### Project Specific ###

platforms
plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree about platforms but less about plugins.

I think it's a good thing to keep track of what version of plugins you've been using in a specific version of your app.

New version of plugins may come with bug corrections or with new bugs or sometimes some plugins repositories may disapear and you wouldn't be able to build your app without finding a replacement.

I keep the plugins folder under version control. What I added to ignore list is the platform specific json files in the plugins folder like android.json, ios.json,windows.json...

Comment: Shameless plug for my Cordova gitignore:
https://gist.github.com/elliot-labs/c92b3e52053906816074170ada511962